# Update and upgrade error 12.04 and 13.04

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, updates, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and the update manager keeps requesting I do a partial upgrade to for Ubuntu 13.04 kernel headers and image. I only have notices to upgrade on long term releases. Are these kernel headers and image needed for Precise if not how to I get around/rid of them. I have no 13.04 software sources and I did not try to upgrade to 13.04.

Comment: what is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep raring
`

Comment: Running that code does not have any output.

Comment: well that means , your sources.list not consist of raring content. ok whats the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response travelling. There is nothing unusual it just runs through the software sources updates what it needs. No errors or anything.

Comment: You still getting such upgrade notification ?

Comment: Yes, I still have the upgrade notification

Comment: Yes still have it

Comment: try the answer and let me know. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open in your terminal and type

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Then it will open a file and it looks like [image]

There place the prompt value as either `lts` or `never`.

No problem with `never` value because you will get notified by web automatically if any version released.

hope that helps.